# Runas a certain xls file

Tags: excel, batch-file, cmd, runas

I need to write a batch script which opens a certain xls file on behalf of another user account.
runas separately works OK:

```
runas /profile /user:username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"
```

excel connector is also OK:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE /r C:\fol der\file.xls"
```

but together it's not:

```
runas /profile /user:username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE /r C:\fol der\file.xls"
```

It can't handle the path of the xls file if there is space anywhere.

Comment: You could try to add ^ before the space to escape it. `""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /r "C:\fol der\file.xls""` could help, too.

Comment: Try this: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't have path of the xls file. I use `%cd%` variable as the bat and the xls files are placed in the same folder. Therefore I don't know what to escape in advance.

Comment: But using double quotes still might work. You could put your %CD% variable in quotes.

Comment: Tried using double quotes, but every time I get the runas manual. It doesn't run that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [RUNAS - Execute a program under a different user account](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html): `RUNAS` used backslash `\` as an escape character (not the standard `^` used by other `CMD` commands). Moreover, `runas /?` gives next example literally:

```
runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""
```

Hence, your line should be as follows:

```
runas /profile /user:username "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE\" /r \"C:\fol der\file.xls\""
```